# Display Value of Variable of type Object in SSIS?

Tags: sql, ssis

Below Query Populate the variable FullResultSet in `SQLTask`

```
SELECT ped.BaselineId,ped.[Hour] FROM PingErrorDataset ped
```

I want to display the value of variable type of Object in Script Task of `SSIS`.

```
MessageBox.Show(Dts.Variables["FullResultSet"].Value.ToString());
```

Output is

```
System.__ComObject
```

Expected OutPut
Value of FullResultSet should be value

Comment: If you have 5 rows, what do you want to show? You can write script that steps through the ADO recordset object but why do you want to display something in SSIS?

Comment: I have a foreach loop i am using value for teting check values of variables

Comment: Do you mean a SSIS for each loop, not a code for each loop? Your code should use the iterated value not the FullResultSet value

Comment: You need to cast the object to a `DataTable` to iterate over the values: `DataTable yourTable = (Dts.Variables["User::FullResultSet"].Value as DataSet).Tables[0];`

Comment: Look at the code used here:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17990992/ssis-display-variable-values-in-script-task

Answer (score 0):

In `Foreach` loop go to variable mapping map your required variable and assign respective position 0 or 1
Alter `column` datatype in `table` from   `varchar(Max)` to  `varchar(8000)` it will work.